# complexity of a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I apologize in advance if my question is silly :-)

Suppose I have a tree of objects, simply defined as follows:

- there is a root object
- the root has direct children objects
- each child object can have children of its own
- and so on

Is there a formal way to define the complexity (Compl) of such a tree?

For example, if I have the two trees

- A: a root and N direct children
- B: a root and N objects but on more than one level

I would expect Compl(B) > Compl(A)

Thanks in advance for patience! :-)

Comment: A simple implementation might be a number of parent nodes: The tree A has only one parent node (the root node), the tree B has many parent nodes. However it may turn out too simple. Suppose trees C, D and E, each with two children to the root node. Now append 2 children to each of the two root's children in C, append 20 children to each of the two in D and append one and 100 children to the two in E. How would you order them by 'complexity'? All C, D and E have.the same number (3) of parent nodes...

Comment: you can define whatever you want (if it is not contradictory) . If you say "to define the complexity" you speak as if t sis already clear what the complexity of a tree is. What is the complexity of a tree? Maybe the well knonw "height" of a tree is what you want?

Comment: well, thanks :-) I am not sure such a definition can exist. I do not know if there is a general mathematical formulation. I only know that the question does not seem meaningless :-) If it can be turned into something that can be computed... that is exactly what I do not know :-)

Comment: My first idea is as follows. The root is level 0. The children of the root are level 1. The children of all elements of level 1 are level 2, and so on. Then I would define Compl as (number of objects of level 1) x (weight for level 1) + (number of objects of level 2) x (weight for level 2)+... where weights could just be 1,2...

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this compexity formula?

Comment: I want to give different scores to different trees that will have to do with objects in the informatic sense :-)